# How to Rearrange rectangles on canvas after modifying height of any rectangle in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, drawrectangle

I am adding `Rectangle` from grid cell values that is being entered by user directly in grid rows. When i modify value of specific column say `Thickness` i.e `Height` then then it increases `Height` of selected row rectangle but it doesnt rearrange all rectangle below it exactly after the selected row rectangle.

In xaml.cs

```
public class MyLayer : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{

    public string Thickness { get; set; }
    public string OffsetRight { get; set; }
    public string OffsetLeft { get; set; }
    public string Material { get; set; }
    public string MaterialPopup { get; set; }
    public Rectangle rectangle { get; set; }

    public GlassRectangle GlassRectangle { get; set; }
    public MaterialLayer()
    {
        GlassRectangle = new GlassRectangle();

    }
    event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    {
        add { }
        remove {  }
    }
}

public class GlassRectangle
{

    public Rectangle Rectangle { get; set; }
    public double Top = 0;
    public GlassRectangle()
    {
        Rectangle = new Rectangle();

    }
}

private void gridInner_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string cellValue = string.Empty;
            MyLayer currentLayer = ((MyLayer)(e.Row));

            if (e.Column.HeaderCaption.ToString() == "Thickness")
            {

                cellValue =(e.Value.ToString());
                //there is alredy a rectangle - means this is edit mode
                if (currentLayer.rectangle != null)
                {
                    currentLayer.rectangle.Height = Convert.ToDouble(cellValue);
                    currentLayer.rectangle.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0));

                }
                //else this is insert mode
                else
                {

                    currentLayer.rectangle = CreateRectangle(cellValue);
                }

            }

        }

 protected Rectangle  CreateRectangle(string cellval)
        {
            Rectangle newrect = new Rectangle();
            newrect.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
            newrect.StrokeThickness = 1;
            if (cellval.ToString().Contains("."))
            {
                newrect.Height = Convert.ToDouble(cellval) * 100;
            }
            else
            {
                newrect.Height = Convert.ToDouble(cellval);
            }
            newrect.Width = width;
            Canvas.SetLeft(newrect, 100);
            double canvasTop = 0.0;
            if (canvasboard.Children.Count > 0)
            {
                var lastChildIndex = canvasboard.Children.Count - 1;
                var lastChild = canvasboard.Children[lastChildIndex] as FrameworkElement;
                if (lastChild != null)
                    //lastChild.Height-1: so that it come extactly on existing if set to +1 it comes below first rectangle
                    canvasTop = Canvas.GetTop(lastChild) + lastChild.Height - 1;
            }

            Canvas.SetTop(newrect, canvasTop);
            val = val + 1;
            newrect.Tag = val;
            canvasboard.Children.Add(newrect);
            //rectangle = rect;

            foreach (UIElement ui in canvasboard.Children)
            {
                if (ui.GetType() == typeof(Rectangle))
                {
                    itemstoremove.Add(ui);
                }
            }

            return newrect;
        }
```

**NEW EVENT Method:**

```
private void gridMaterialInner_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string cellValue = string.Empty;
            string cellOldValue = string.Empty;
            MyLayer currentLayer = ((MyLayer)(e.Row));
            if (e.Column.HeaderCaption.ToString() == "Thickness")
            {
                //current cell value
                cellValue =(e.Value.ToString());// GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, gridMaterialInner.Columns["LastName"]).ToString();
                //there is alredy a rectangle - means this is edit mode
                double currentheight = 0.0;
                double oldht = 0.0;
                // old cell value
                if (e.OldValue != null)
                {
                    cellOldValue = (e.OldValue.ToString());
                }
                if (currentLayer.rectangle != null)
                {
                    if (cellValue.ToString().Contains("."))
                    {
                        currentheight = Convert.ToDouble(cellValue) * 100;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentheight = Convert.ToDouble(cellValue) * 100;
                    }
                    if (cellOldValue.ToString().Contains("."))
                    {
                        oldht = Convert.ToDouble(cellOldValue) * 100;
                    }
                    else if(cellOldValue!=string.Empty)
                    {
                        oldht = Convert.ToDouble(cellOldValue) * 100;
                    }

                    currentLayer.rectangle.Height = currentheight;
                    currentLayer.rectangle.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0));

                    //Refresh();
                    //Get the index of selected row
                    int layerIndex = materialBindlist.IndexOf(currentLayer);
                    for(int i = layerIndex; i < materialBindlist.Count-1; i++)
                    {
                        //set the top position of all other rectangles that are below selected rectangle/row
                        //(Current-Old)+Top
                        Canvas.SetTop(materialBindlist[i + 1].rectangle, (currentheight - oldht) + materialBindlist[i + 1].GlassRectangle.Top);
                        //Canvas.SetTop(materialBindlist[i].rectangle, (currentheight - oldht) + materialBindlist[i + 1].GlassRectangle.Top);

                    }
                }
                //else this is insert mode
                else
                {
                    //MaterialLayer object
                    currentLayer.rectangle = CreateRectangle(cellValue);
                    //store Top & Rectangle object in GlassRectangle class which is referenced in MaterialLayer class
                    currentLayer.GlassRectangle.Rectangle = currentLayer.rectangle;
                    currentLayer.GlassRectangle.Top = canvasTop;
                }

            }

        }
```

*This create rectangle one after other like Stacked item on canvas. But when i modify the value of `Thickness` column which is `Height` of `Rectangle` it reflects on canvas but the Other Rectangle below must appear after the Changed Height of current rectangle.*

**Note: I cant use WrapPanel in my application. Just to modify existing code using Canvas.**

Help Appreciated!

**Modified For Loop in CellChange Event:**

```
int layerIndex = materialBindlist.IndexOf(currentLayer);
                    for(int i = layerIndex; i < materialBindlist.Count-1; i++)
                    {
                        //set the top position of all other rectangles that are below selected rectangle/row
                        //(Current-Old)+Top
                        double top=Convert.ToDouble((currentHeight - oldHeight) + materialBindlist[i + 1].GlassRectangle.Top);
                        Canvas.SetTop(materialBindlist[i + 1].rectangle,top);

                        materialBindlist[i + 1].GlassRectangle.Top = top;



                    }
```

Comment: Dump the Canvas and write a custom Panel with overrides for Measure and Arrange .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for can be done even with a `Canvas` however you should really consider using something like an `ItemsControl` for this.

**Solution when forced to use `Canvas`:**

```
private void Refresh() {
  for (int i = 1; i < canvasboard.Children.Count; ++i) {
    var currentElement = canvasboard.Children[i] as FrameworkElement;
    var previousElement = canvasboard.Children[i - 1] as FrameworkElement;
    if (currentElement == null || previousElement == null)
      return;
    var requiredTop = Canvas.GetTop(previousElement) + previousElement.Height - 1;
    if (Math.Abs(Canvas.GetTop(currentElement) - requiredTop) > 0.0)
      Canvas.SetTop(currentElement, requiredTop);
  }
}
```

Now call this function "after" you change the size of an existing element in the `Canvas` and it will re-position the elements accordingly to suit the new dimension. In your code, it would be called from the `gridInner_CellValueChanged(...)` function after you set the new height in "edit" mode.

**What you should try to do:**

If your able to persuade whoever you need to and get to use something like an `ItemsControl`, this will be so much simpler.

say a rough example:

xaml could be:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

with `Items` declared as `public ObservableCollection<Rectangle> Items { get; set; }` in code.

Now your `Add()` function could just be:

```
private void Add() {
  var rect = new Rectangle {
    Stroke = Brushes.Red,
    StrokeThickness = 1,
    Height = Convert.ToDouble(txtheight.Text),
    Width = 100
  };
  Items.Add(rect);
}
```

and as for updates when your editing existing control's that would be automatic in this case. There is no hard-coded positioning as the Layout container takes care of all that mess for you.

You can ofcourse switch the `Items` collection type to your own custom control type `MyLayer` and with it implementing INPC, changes would still continue to be automatic. You'd have to define a `DataTemplate` now to get your Item to be rendered but that's like 3 lines of work in just xaml.

You can also just work of the `Items` property directly when needing to tweak an exisiting control than having to reference the `ItemsControl` in code-behind. Binding's should take care of the updates to the view automatically.

Comment: Hi @Viv thanks for replying! but this code works only when i increase existing size but when i decrease the size again it wont re-arrange..! any idea?

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE Yeh that was my bad where I only was checking for the previous item expanding and not shrinking. I've updated the function in my answer. Give that a try and it should be fine.

Comment: hello @Viv , i have added "New Method" code will you plz help me about the for loop that i have used to set the below rectangles auto adjust. This is due to just now i come to know that canvas may contain other graphics also later so, i have added Rectangle reference.

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE Hey, I'm sorry but I don't follow your question. Not really sure what your asking me to look for and help. I can see you've edited and added a new function? what exactly are you asking me for? Do you want to know where to call the `Refresh()` function from or is there something wrong with the function?

Comment: hi @Viv, actually i am saving the Rectangle references. When i change height only first time it work but not works for other row changes. Your code is absolutely fine. but not able to use your code due to other elements in canvas so modified my code in for loop. I have changed the current for loop with new one plz check post and it works now! Thanks for showing interest :)

Answer (score 1):

**Modified for loop in Cell Change Event:**

```
int layerIndex = materialBindlist.IndexOf(currentLayer);
                    for(int i = layerIndex; i < materialBindlist.Count-1; i++)
                    {
                        //set the top position of all other rectangles that are below selected rectangle/row
                        //(Current-Old)+Top
                        double top=Convert.ToDouble((currentHeight - oldHeight) + materialBindlist[i + 1].GlassRectangle.Top);
                        Canvas.SetTop(materialBindlist[i + 1].rectangle,top);

                        materialBindlist[i + 1].GlassRectangle.Top = top;



                    }
```

it works now..!Thanks to all!